# setting an object orientated javascript variable with if statement

Tags: javascript, object, if-statement

I am trying to set an object orientated javascript variable using an if statement.
If the user enters a string color it will use the appropriate array.
I set the vertices array but the color array is giving me hassle.
  I keep getting "undefined" on the alert box. 
Its my first time to attempt this and I think Im using **this.** wrong.

```
<script type="text/javascript">


    function Cube( vertexPoints, Color )
    {
        this.vertices = vertexPoints;
        if(Color == "yellow" || Color == "Yellow")
        {
            this.colorArray = [
                [1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0],
                [1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0],
                [1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0],
                [1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0],
                [1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0],
                [1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0]
            ];
        }
        else if(Color == "red" || Color == "Red")
        {
            this.colorArray = [
                [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0],
                [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0],
                [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0],
                [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0],
                [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0],
                [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
            ];
        }
        else if(Color == "green" || Color == "Green")
        {
            this.colorArray = [
                [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0],
                [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0],
                [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0],
                [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0],
                [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0],
                [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
            ];
        }
        else if(Color == "pink" || Color == "Pink")
        {
            this.colorArray = [
                [1.0, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0],
                [1.0, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0],
                [1.0, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0],
                [1.0, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0],
                [1.0, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0],
                [1.0, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0]
            ];
        }
        else if(Color == "purple" || Color == "Purple")
        {
            this.colorArray = [
                [1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0],
                [1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0],
                [1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0],
                [1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0],
                [1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0],
                [1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0]
            ];
        }
        else if(Color == "blue" || Color == "Blue")
        {
            this.colorArray = [
                [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0],
                [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0],
                [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0],
                [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0],
                [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0],
                [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0]
            ];
        }
        else 
        {
         this.colorArray = [
                [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
                [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
                [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
                [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
                [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
                [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
         ]
        }
    }


    function hi()
    {
        alert("Hi my vertices is "+Cube.vertices);
        alert("Hi my vertices is "+Cube.colorArray);
    }

    function set()
    {
        Cube.vertices = [
            // Front face
            -1.0, -1.0,  1.0,
             1.0, -1.0,  1.0,
             1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
            -1.0,  1.0,  1.0,

            // Back face
            -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
            -1.0,  1.0, -1.0,
             1.0,  1.0, -1.0,
             1.0, -1.0, -1.0,

            // Top face
            -1.0,  1.0, -1.0,
            -1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
             1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
             1.0,  1.0, -1.0,

            // Bottom face
            -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
             1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
             1.0, -1.0,  1.0,
            -1.0, -1.0,  1.0,

            // Right face
             1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
             1.0,  1.0, -1.0,
             1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
             1.0, -1.0,  1.0,

            // Left face
            -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
            -1.0, -1.0,  1.0,
            -1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
            -1.0,  1.0, -1.0
        ];

        Cube.Color = "yellow";
    }
</script>
<body>
<button type="button" onclick="set();">Set the properties</button>
<button type="button" onclick="hi();">Push me</button>
</body>
</head>
</html>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with your code and some improvements you can make.

Your Cube object represents what can be thought of as a class in other languages.  Your class has some properties.  You need to create a helper (setter) method to set the color matrix you want.  Also, you can minimize a lot of your code by using a `switch`:

```
function Cube(vertices, color) {
    this.vertices = vertices;
    this.setColor(color);
}

Cube.prototype.setColor = function(color) {
    switch (color.toLowerCase()) {
        case "yellow":
            this.colorArray = [];
            break;

        case "red":
            this.colorArray = [];
            break;

        case "purple":
            this.colorArray = [];
            break;

        [...]
    }
}

// create a new instance of your Cube class
var cubeInstance = new Cube([0, 1, 0 ...], "yellow");

// then change the color to red
cubeInstance.setColor("red");
```

Comment: This is what I was trying to do.I have used classes in C++ and this explains exactly what I was attempting. Thank you

Comment: This is the quick and dirty way.  The best way to achieve inheritance and so forth is to use `Object.create` - [read about it here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create)

Answer (score 1):

```
function hi()
{
    alert("Hi my vertices is "+Cube.vertices);
    alert("Hi my vertices is "+Cube.colorArray);
}
```

What is `Cube`, isn't that the class name, rather than the instance of the object?

The same goes for your `set()` function.

If you want to access the actual instance of the Cube you are in, then store it in another variable so you can use it later:

```
var self = this;
function hi()
{
    alert("Hi my vertices is "+self.vertices);
    alert("Hi my vertices is "+self.colorArray);
}
```

Comment: ya that did it i messed up as you said with the `Cube.vertices`.
So I made a var x = new Cube(vertices,color);
thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are several approaches possible. One can be as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">


    function Cube( vertexPoints, Color )
    {
        this.vertices = vertexPoints;
        if(Color == "yellow" || Color == "Yellow")
        {
            this.colorArray = [
                [1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0],
                [1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0],
                [1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0],
                [1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0],
                [1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0],
                [1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0]
            ];
        }
        else if(Color == "red" || Color == "Red")
        {
            this.colorArray = [
                [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0],
                [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0],
                [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0],
                [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0],
                [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0],
                [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
            ];
        }
        else if(Color == "green" || Color == "Green")
        {
            this.colorArray = [
                [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0],
                [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0],
                [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0],
                [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0],
                [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0],
                [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
            ];
        }
        else if(Color == "pink" || Color == "Pink")
        {
            this.colorArray = [
                [1.0, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0],
                [1.0, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0],
                [1.0, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0],
                [1.0, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0],
                [1.0, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0],
                [1.0, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0]
            ];
        }
        else if(Color == "purple" || Color == "Purple")
        {
            this.colorArray = [
                [1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0],
                [1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0],
                [1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0],
                [1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0],
                [1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0],
                [1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0]
            ];
        }
        else if(Color == "blue" || Color == "Blue")
        {
            this.colorArray = [
                [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0],
                [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0],
                [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0],
                [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0],
                [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0],
                [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0]
            ];
        }
        else 
        {
         this.colorArray = [
                [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
                [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
                [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
                [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
                [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
                [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
         ]
        }
    }

    var cube = new Cube(); // can use parameters here, define object cube


    function hi(cube)
    {
        alert("Hi my vertices is "+cube.vertices);
        alert("Hi my vertices is "+cube.colorArray);
    }

    function set(cube)
    {
        cube.vertices = [
            // Front face
            -1.0, -1.0,  1.0,
             1.0, -1.0,  1.0,
             1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
            -1.0,  1.0,  1.0,

            // Back face
            -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
            -1.0,  1.0, -1.0,
             1.0,  1.0, -1.0,
             1.0, -1.0, -1.0,

            // Top face
            -1.0,  1.0, -1.0,
            -1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
             1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
             1.0,  1.0, -1.0,

            // Bottom face
            -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
             1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
             1.0, -1.0,  1.0,
            -1.0, -1.0,  1.0,

            // Right face
             1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
             1.0,  1.0, -1.0,
             1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
             1.0, -1.0,  1.0,

            // Left face
            -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
            -1.0, -1.0,  1.0,
            -1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
            -1.0,  1.0, -1.0
        ];

        cube.Color = "yellow";

    }
</script>
<body>
<button type="button" onclick="set(cube);">Set the properties</button>
<button type="button" onclick="hi(cube);">Push me</button>
</body>
</head>
</html>
```

other can be:

```
Cube.prototype.set = function (v, c) { this.vertices = v; this.color = c } //call cube.set(v,c);
```